# CSS trouble to place buttom border under logos top right of the page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a border under my  logos at the top of the page right.

Before I'm adding `position:absolute;` to the div, my 2 logos are placed where I want them to be under the contact me top right. But the border on the left side of the page, when I put `position:absolute;` it moves but the logos jump down the page.

[image]

```css
css #para {
  margin-right: 1.66%;
  float: right;
  font-family: indie flower;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.fb {
  width: 27px;
  float: right;
  right: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 3px;
  top: 35px;
}

#in {
  margin-top: 4px;
  width: 25px;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 40px;
  top: 35px;
}

div {
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid red;
  width: 60px;
  right: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<p id="para">Contact me </p>
<div>
  <img class="fb" width="10" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picons-social/57/46-facebook-512.png">
  <img id="in" width="25" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/69/69366.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `float: right` on your `#para` and `div`. Use a `<span>` with [`clear`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp) attribute to prevent `div` from overlapping. No need for any absolute positioning. As you can see this simplifies the code a lot.

```
.clear {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

PS: Avoid adding CSS to tags like `div`.

```css
#para {
  margin-right: 1.66%;
  float: right;
  font-family: indie flower;
}

.clear {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.fb {
  width: 27px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

#in {
  margin-top: 4px;
  width: 25px;
}

#icons {
  float: right;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid red;
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<p id="para">Contact me </p>
<span class="clear"></span>
<div id="icons">
  <img class="fb" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picons-social/57/46-facebook-512.png">
  <img id="in" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/69/69366.png">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks , ill try it out now , basicly i tried something and it worked for me , i pulled out the images out of the div and changed the div's css todiv {

 border-bottom: 1.5px solid red;
 width:60px;
 right:5px;
 position:absolute;
 top:65px;
 margin-right: 1.66%;

 }

Comment: Yeah, there are many ways to make it work. The idea is to go for the most simple and least hardcoded way. Using `position:absolute` and hardcoding `top` and other attributes, can be cumbersome and it will create a non responsive design.

Comment: @alex92l1Please mark as the right answer if it helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the snippet you have posted, it looks like it may be because you are positioning the icons absolute while not moving the container (which has the border).

I would recommend the below. I have removed the absolute positioning from the icons, along with the floats, and instead have positioned the icon container.

```css
css #para {
  margin-right: 1.66%;
  float: right;
  font-family: indie flower;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.fb {
  width: 27px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

#in {
  margin-top: 4px;
  width: 25px;
}

.icon-container {
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid red;
  width: 60px;
  right: 5px;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<p id="para">Contact me </p>
<div class="icon-container">
  <img class="fb" width="10" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picons-social/57/46-facebook-512.png">
  <img id="in" width="25" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/69/69366.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This out. And one thing style elements by *class* not *id*

```css
#left {
 margin-right: 1.66%;
 float: left;
 font-family: indie flower;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0px;
    }

.fb {
 width: 27px;
    }

#in {
 width: 25px;
    }

#right {
 float: right;
 text-align: center;
 border-bottom: 1.5px solid red;
 right: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>question reality.</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
 <div id="right"> 
  <p>Contact me </p>
  <img id="in" width="25" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/69/69366.png">
  <img class="fb" width="10" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picons-social/57/46-facebook-512.png">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```